# .NET Core 3.1: Serilog - WriteTo AzureTable Storage - Create table if not exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, azure-table-storage, serilog

My app is .NET Core 3.1. based and I am using Serilog for logging. Sink that I use to store logs is AzureTableStorage.
Is there a way to a set an option to create table if not exists when writing logs to Azure Table Storage? Table is created once app is started, but what if I want to create tables dynamically, for example, by days?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe Az table client provides a CreateIfNotExists() method for just this purpose.

Comment: I want something that will check if table exists every time it wants to write to the table. Currently, this check is performed only first time I run the app. When app is running and I delete the table which was created when app was started and then do something that should be logged, there is nothing new created.

Comment: Thats precisely the CreateIfNotExist() does. Have a look at the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.createifnotexists?view=azure-dotnet and there are other methods also like Exists() etc which you can try.

Comment: Not really. It creates the table when I first time run the app, but if I delete table during runtime and produce some logs, they are not written anywhere. 
I configured all this in Startup.cs, maybe I should set it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're essentially after a 'rolling' version of the [Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage) sink that creates a new table per day, and that is also resilient to the table suddenly disappearing while the app is running. Neither of those things are currently supported by the sink in its current form, so you'd have to create your own `ILogEventSink` to achieve what you're after. Some things to consider:

- A good place to start is probably by looking at the existing `AzureBatchingTableStorageSink`.
- To handle the case where the table is deleted while the app is running, be aware that the `CreateIfNotExists()` method makes an HTTP request to the blob service every time it is called, so doing it for every log event (or batch) will effectively double the number of HTTP requests made by the sink. Instead, you could optimistically write events to the table and only create the table if you get an error code indicating that the table does not exist.
- The table name will have to be dynamically determined based on the `LogEvent.Timestamp` property. Since your event logging mechanism needs to account for the table not existing (as explained above), there's no real need to explicitly create a new table when the name changes. This should happen automatically when you attempt to write a log event.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Case I mentioned as an example wasn't real case, I just tried to find the way to reproduce something close to my actual scenario where I have to check if the table exists every time log is created. I have also googled a lot about this and didn't find that AzureTableStorage sink support what I wanted to achieve. I will consider this option of writing a new sink or to try to achieve something close with some of the existing sinks(AzureBlobStorage for example).